# How to sync selection index between two ListBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two listboxes: listBox1, listBox2.

If i select the item in first listBox1, item of the same index must be automatically selected in listBox2.
So, If i select item 1 in listbox1 then, item 1 selected automatically in listbox2 and so on.

Not: I found some examples but not work.

```
private void listBoxControl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ listBoxControl5.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex; }
```

**Edit:**

I solved it using the selected index code in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888142/how-to-sync-selection-index-between-two-listboxes?noredirect=1#comment51693905_31888142) in SelectedValueChanged Event.

```
private void listBoxControl2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxControl5.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Comment: `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;`

Comment: I use it in listbox2_SelectedIndexChanged event and not working

Comment: Edit your post with the code you are using.  Are the events wired up?

Comment: private void listBoxControl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
listBoxControl5.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex;
}

Comment: I used listbox2 inside panel and listbox5 in another panel

Comment: Does the event run when an item is selected?  I'm guessing you didn't wire up the events correctly.

Comment: When i select an item in listbox2, I can do another  things but this code not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that you may want to explore more, try to add `ListBox`to your form (in this sample 3 listboxes) it should look like the following:

[image]

And here's the source that would select the same index whenever you click on an item on it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeListBoxes();
    }

    private void InitializeListBoxes()
    {
        //Populate listboxes
        listBox1.Items.Add("Apple");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Orange");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Mango");

        listBox2.Items.Add("Milk");
        listBox2.Items.Add("Cheese");
        listBox2.Items.Add("Butter");

        listBox3.Items.Add("Coffee");
        listBox3.Items.Add("Cream");
        listBox3.Items.Add("Sugar");

        //Subscribe to same events
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        listBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;
        listBox3.SelectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

What happens is on the `InitializeListBoxes` you subscribe to the same event which would trigger the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and select appropriate item from each of the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem, you can use a pattern called Observer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, you will have to create a notifier method in the listboxes that you want to notify. When you select an item in listBox1, you will call the notifier method of listBox2.

Comment: It's very difficult but i'll try

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the selected index code in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888142/how-to-sync-selection-index-between-two-listboxes?noredirect=1#comment51693905_31888142) in SelectedValueChanged Event.

```
private void listBoxControl2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxControl5.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and easiest way can be via MouseDown event:

```
        private void lstBoxes_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstBox = (ListBox)sender;
        lstBx1.SelectedIndex = lstBox.SelectedIndex;
        lstBx2.SelectedIndex = lstBox.SelectedIndex;
        lstBx3.SelectedIndex = lstBox.SelectedIndex;
    }
```